# _co.addCourse() is not a function- even though I have defined it in the ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

So I am very new to Ionic-angular development, and right now I am just looking to define a function in my home.ts file, and call it in my home.html file, for doing a basic Create in my FirebaseDB. This is my home.html file:

```
home.html
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
        <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addCourse()">
          <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
</ion-content>
```

and this is my home.ts file

```
home.ts
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  songsList: AngularFireList<any>;
  songs: Observable<any>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public afDB: AngularFireDatabase, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    this.songsList = this.afDB.list('/songs');
    this.songs = this.songsList.valueChanges();

    function addCourse(){
      let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Course Name',
        message: "Enter the Course Code",
        inputs: [
          {
            name: 'title',
            placeholder: 'Title'
          },
        ],
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: data => {
              console.log('Cancelled');
            }
          },
          {
            text: 'Save',
            handler: data => {
              const newSongRef = this.songs.push({});

              newSongRef.set({
                id: newSongRef.key,
                title: data.title
              });
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      prompt.present();
    }
  }


    }
```

I get an error when I remove the declaration 'function' from `function addCourse(){...}`, but I get this error on the website

```
_co.addCourse() is not a function. (In '_co.addCourse()','_co.addCourse() is undefined)
```

First I thought this is because I should define the function outside the constructor, but then how do I call the database or the Alert Controller?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: You've defined it within the constructor, not within the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have the keyword function and it should be outside of the constructor, change it as,

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public afDB: AngularFireDatabase, public alertCtrl: AlertController) {
}

addCourse(){
}
```

Comment: would I do this.songsList = this.afDB.list('/songs'); and this.songs = this.songsList.valueChanges(); outside the constructor too?

Comment: yeah inside constructor

Comment: when I move those inside the constructor, I get an error that the push method does not exist on type Observable<any>. I understand this is because songs is an Observable, and it is connected to database inside the constructor, but how do I fix this?

Comment: you need to initialize songs array  songs: Observable<any> = [];

Comment: Worked! Thanks.